# Date Parsing with simpledateformatter

Tags: java, android, parsing, date, format

Im trying to parse the following date:

```
 Wed Aug 27 13:08:45 +0000 2008
```

(Is for Twitter API 1.1)

I make the following format:

```
/**
 * Large twitter date format sample: "Wed Aug 27 13:08:45 +0000 2008"
 */
private static final String LARGE_TWITTER_DATE_FORMAT = "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy";
```

but it says:

```
java.text.ParseException: Unparseable date: "Sun Dec 25 14:49:28 +0000 2011" (at offset 0)
     at java.text.DateFormat.parse(DateFormat.java:626)
```

What im doing wrong?

Thanks

Comment: Which is your locale? In other words, if you use the same `SimpleDateFormat` to format a `new java.util.Date()`, which language is the string that you get.

Comment: the two date strings don't match - the one in the exception and the one you're trying to parse. be careful of odd whitespace in the date string: any leading spaces?

Comment: see this http://docs.oracle.com/javase/1.4.2/docs/api/java/text/SimpleDateFormat.html

Answer (score 4, accepted):

I think this is locale issue. Running that code on my machine gives me expected result with no exception.

Hint: Parsing for `ENGLISH` locale **works good**

```
 String LARGE_TWITTER_DATE_FORMAT = "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy";
 String twiDate = "Wed Aug 27 13:08:45 +0000 2008";
 new SimpleDateFormat(LARGE_TWITTER_DATE_FORMAT, Locale.ENGLISH)
       .parse(twiDate).getHours());
```

Parsing for FRANCE `locale` **causes the same error** that you have

```
String LARGE_TWITTER_DATE_FORMAT = "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy";
String twiDate = "Wed Aug 27 13:08:45 +0000 2008";
System.out.println(new SimpleDateFormat(LARGE_TWITTER_DATE_FORMAT, Locale.FRANCE)
                .parse(twiDate).getHours());
```

Comment: That was what im missing, I am creating the SimpleDateFormat without Locale. Thanks!

Answer (score -1):

The following works for me

```
import java.text.ParseException;
import java.text.SimpleDateFormat;


public class Test {

    private static final String LARGE_TWITTER_DATE_FORMAT = "EEE MMM dd HH:mm:ss Z yyyy";

    /**
     * @param args
     */
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        SimpleDateFormat df = new SimpleDateFormat(LARGE_TWITTER_DATE_FORMAT);

        try {
            System.out.println(df.parse("Wed Aug 27 13:08:45 +0000 2008 "));
        } catch (ParseException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }
    }
}
```